# Regex matching names in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a simple pattern `LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MI_IDNUMBER` that I've matched with `^[a-zA-Z0-9, ]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. The problem I'm running into now are records where the person has a last name with a hyphen like `WALKER-REYES, ANNA T_AW12345`. I've tried incorporating something like `(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)` into it but this only identifies that `LASTNAME` in the string. What's the best way to string this all together? Not all names will have hyphens.

Comment: Are you only trying to match a string that matches this format, or are you trying to extract the four values (last and first name, middle initial and ID number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you built your regex is not optimal. You are matching every character, including space, until you find an underscore ( `_` ) and then match the rest. Rather than doing that, you shouldn't match spaces and have every part of your string in different groups.

You can try using this regex, which support hyphens.

```
^(?: ?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+),?){2} ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can test more cases at [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vFPnWt/1)

Comment: I had one quick question on this. I'm coming across records now that have a space between the name and the code `SMITH, JOHN _JS12345`. How would I account for that possibility?

Comment: @AGH_TORN it seams to be matching aswell https://regex101.com/r/vFPnWt/3

Comment: Ah you're correct, however, the regex is also matching strings where the `_` is not present, this is necessary and must be a part of the string for me. Any ideas?

Comment: @AGH_TORN I've created a new regex101 for that. I just forced a `_` to be in between two capture group of letters. https://regex101.com/r/vFPnWt/4